# Django How to add a User Foreignkey inside a User model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I'm trying to insert a foreignkey of the  User inside of the user  model but I keep getting error.
As as user I want to have two purposes, I can do i do a book to get my pets taken care of and also i can take care of other pets

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='John Doe')
  pet_sitter = models.ForeignKey('User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)//--->User inside User
  I tried get_user_model() it showed errors too//
  pet_appointments= models.ManyToManyField(
    'User',
    through=Booking,
    through_fields=('patient', 'doctor')
    )

class Booking(models.Model):
  start_date = models.DateTimeField()  
  end_date = models.DateTimeField()
  owner_of_pet = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),related_name = "User",on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
  sitter = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    

enter code here
===============

error
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'api.User' that has not been installed
```

Comment: You can't have same model being the relation to itself that makes no sense. You can create a separate model namely Pet and add relations there.

Comment: I was thining as a user, I want to be a sitter, at the same time I want to be able to give my pet to other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Seems like you have defined some `User` in `api` app, so add that app to the installed apps in `settings.py`:

```py
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "api",
```

Also, it is not really possible or needed to reference the `User` in this way.

I imagine your `models.py` to be something like this:

```py
from api.models import CustomUser
from django.db import models


class Pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pet_sitter = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pets', blank=True,null=True)

class Booking(models.Model):
    pet = models.ForeignKey(Pet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()  
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Check the source code here: https://github.com/almazkun/petshop